# Determining levels of Phenylalanine in common foods

Tags: nutrition, labeling, amino-acids

As a result from my recent concerns regarding [Phenylketonuria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylketonuria), I would like to ask the community:

> Where can I find the quantities of [Phenylalanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylalanine) in common
> nutritional items such as milk, eggs, cheese, nuts, soybeans, chicken,
> beef, pork, beans and fish?

I am aware it may vary between producers but I am at a loss when a [label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutrition_facts_label) only states *contains phenylalanine* (without mention to the amount). Would there be a resource available for researching the levels that occur naturally?

Comment: This organization looks like it should be able to help you out:
https://www.npkua.org/

Comment: I don't have PKU, neither is reaching out to an advisory board related to my question.

Comment: I understand; the organization I suggested claims they have resources to help folks live with PKU, presumably including tables of how much PA occurs naturally in various types of food. Looking into it further, I see that they are selling their various resources -- sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems this is more what you were asking for:

Food Data Chart
http://apjcn.nhri.org.tw/server/info/books-phds/books/foodfacts/html/data/data2e.html

Table of Phenylalanine Content of Foods: Comparative Analysis of Data Compiled in Food Composition Tables
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5509543/

Comment: Yes thank you Armand, these I found informative.